# FB share rarely working on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app with integrated Facebook sharing.  It's been working for several years now.

I recently updated to the latest SDK, and now when I try to share, it succeeds maybe 10% of the time, but usually fails with the following logging:

> plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post interrupted
>   Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.facebook.Facebook.ShareExtension}
>   didCancel.

(The didCancel is my own logging to show that the didCancel callback gets hit).  I'm using version 4.29 of the SDK, with the following items added to my plist, based on suggestions I've read elsewhere:

> FacebookAppID
>   FacebookDisplayName
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes         fbapi20150629
>                                       fbshareextension
>                                       fbapi
>                                       fbauth2

Any suggestions you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A quick footnote, I've been seeing this behavior two days in a row, so I don't think it's an intermittent connectivity problem.

Answer (score 0):

This morning I had the same error and hours later it is working correctly, so I guess it is related to Facebook. So my conclusion is that if it has been working properly before, it should work well again after a while.